# Flutter time zone package give the device time

Tags: flutter, timezone

i want to get time now in Cairo using timezone package independent of device date
but unfortunately it gives me the device date time . i don't know where is the error hope some one help me . the code below

```
DateTime returnCommonDate(){
tz.initializeTimeZones();
final egyptTimeZone = tz.getLocation('Africa/Cairo');
final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(egyptTimeZone);
print("=========================this is egypt time ${now}");
return now;
```

}

Comment: You asked for the time "now".  That's the time according to your device.  The TZDateTime probably properly has the timezone as Cairo.  How are you deciding this is the wrong value?  For this, we must know your local time zone, your local time, and the timestring shown by the message.

Comment: I don't want to get my device date . My timezone is cairo . I changed the the date manually in my device settings . I want date generate from TZDatetime independent on it

Comment: Unless you do a network time call (with the ntp package), the time will be the time of your device.  Are you distrusting the user that they may be forcing a fake time on you?  Otherwise, I'd just use device time.

Comment: i make a chat app and i send messages to fire base by date time . so i want to make all messages in the same timezone to arrange it.okay how can i use ntp package ?

Comment: Firestore stores datetimes as independent of timezones.  It's only when you read from firestore and display it locally that it's converted to your timezone.  So, it doesn't matter where in the world someone is... if you sort by the server timestamps, it will be correct for what happened in real time.